# diamond structure using asterix in python

Tags: python, nested-loops

i need to print a basic diamond structure using asterix in python. the program should read the number of rows and print an output. eg-if the number of rows is 5 then there should be 3 of the big triangle and 2 of the reversed to give us 5 rows. also this code is cor python 2.7.
sample output should be like if width=5

```
  *
 * *
* * *
 * *
  *
```

this is what i attempted

```
width=input("enter the number of rows")

for num in range(1, width-1 , 1):
    print(('*' * num).center(width))

for num in reversed(range(1, width-2, 1)):
    print(('*' * num).center(width))
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: if this is a homework project, see: http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems

Comment: @shavenwarthog no it is not a homework project please read the tags!!

Comment: @TimZimmermann read the first line....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wasn't supposed to code that, but I like this stuff. This works for both even and odd numbers:

```
rows = input("enter the number of rows")

for num in range(1, rows // 2 + 1) + range((rows + 1) // 2, 0, -1):
    print(' '.join('*' * num).center(rows))
```

*Output `rows = 5`*:

```
  *  
 * * 
* * *
 * * 
  *
```

*Output `rows = 6`*:

```
  *   
 * *  
* * * 
* * * 
 * *  
  *
```

**EDIT**

This is also nice:

```
for num in xrange(rows):
    print(' '.join('*' * min(num + 1, rows - num)).center(rows))
```

Comment: @JohnKugelman True, now it works, as long as the number is odd.

Comment: @JohnKugelman and now also for even numbers ;)

Comment: @enrico.bacis just one more question. please read my edit

Comment: sorry for the delay please read my edit now

Comment: That's a complete different question, you should rollback the edits and post another one.

Comment: I encourage you *not* to post a follow-up question, and instead try to solve these problems yourself. You'll learn much better by doing these exercises on your own. Figuring out why code you've written doesn't work and getting it to work is one of the most fundamental, important, and **fun** parts of programming. Those "aha!" moments are a wonderful thing.

Comment: @JohnKugelman That's why I like these *silly* problems, but you are right, I shouldn't steal others' *aha*!